# Dynamic allocation of string array using void pointer

Tags: c

The problem is as follows. I have a void pointer and I want to allocate string array with that. Is it possible to cast void* to char** like this:

```
void* ptr = (char**)calloc(size, sizeof(char*))
```

and then allocate each row of that table? I'm currently running out of ideas.

Comment: (1) I guess you didn't intend to make `ptr` have the type `void`. (2) There is a missing `)`.

Comment: [Meta: Where is the line for yes/no question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions)

Comment: yes, you can. You do not need the (char**) cast.`void*` just points to any arbitrary chunk of memory.

Comment: If you want to allocate a "string array", if you want to allocate memory for the array and then for each row, it will be much easier if you work with a `char **`.  Why do you want to use `void *` instead?  Yu can do it, but it will be harder.  Every time you do anything with `ptr`, you'll have to cast it back to `char **`.

Comment: I'd like to use that as a pointer to a dynamic array as well as a static array, depending on a value of a specific flag.

Comment: That won't work.  See the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/), [question 6.20](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc3.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psuedo Code that should get you what you need.

```
char **ptr = NULL;    
// Allocates an array of pointers
ptr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (NUM_OF_STRINGS_IN_ARRAY));
If (ptr == NULL)
    return; // Do error handling here
for (int i =0; i < NUM_OF_STRINGS_IN_ARRAY; i++)
{
    // Allocates each string in the array.
    ptr[i] = malloc(strlen(STRING));
    if (ptr[i] == NULL)
    {
        return; // Do error handling here
    }
}
```

Comment: He said he wanted `ptr` to be `void *`.

Comment: Actually, that's what I needed.